# Rails: combining multiple find requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

What I want to do is something like this:

```
searchid = 4

while searchid != -1

  @a += A.find(searchid)
  @b = B.find(searchid)
  searchid = @b.parentid
end
```

The problem being the line

```
@a += A.find(searchid)
```

The error being something like

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for #<A:0x173f9a0>
```

So, how do you combine multiple 'find' requests?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `@a = []` as an array before the `+=` .

```
searchid = 4
@a = []
while searchid != -1

  @a += A.find(searchid)
  @b = B.find(searchid)
  searchid = @b.parentid
end
```

You can combine them like:

```
searchid = 4
@a = []
while searchid != -1

  @a += A.find(searchid)
  @a += B.find(searchid)
  searchid = @a.last.parentid
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.
The error I get is: "TypeError: can't convert A into Array
 from (irb):8:in `+'"

The 'A' being a model and the result of the 'find' being the result from a query to a database.
I'm presuming you would need to create your own '+' function but I don't even know what format the find returns and I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work (with help).
Did the following:

```
@a = []
```

with

```
@a << A.find_by_something(something)
```

seems to have worked.
Also using `@a.compact!` to get rid of the null entries.

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Yep, i just saw that you receive only one element.

Comment: Also if you have to mix up, for example you will receive both single elements and arrays, you can also use the << operator and you have to apply @a.flatten! to have still an array of elements instead of array with arrays.